# BufferedWriter write() not working

Tags: java, file, io

I am trying to write to and write to files through the following code snippet. However the file is created but nothing is written in it. I have already tested the lines structure and it is ok.

```
try{
    File file = new File("../received/"+nameFiles.get(op-1));
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( file, true ) );
    for(String index : lines){
        bw.write(index);
        System.out.println(index);
    }
    System.out.println("Arquivo criado");
}catch(IOException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You should close your writer at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have some flaws in your code:

1. You're never flushing the `BufferedWriter`
2. You're never closing it either

Following code should fix your problem:

```
final File file = new File("../received/"+nameFiles.get(op-1));
try(BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true) )){
    for(String index : lines){
        bw.write(index);
        System.out.println(index);
    }
    System.out.println("Arquivo criado");
} catch(IOException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

The *try with resources* calls the `AutoCloseable#close()` method after it leaves the `try-catch` block. And whenever `close()` is called. The `BufferedWriter` also invokes `flush()` which finally writes to your file.